# Linking GLFW in Eclipse Mars

Tags: c++, eclipse, macos, linker, glfw

I have generated a file called `libglfw3.a` and added the library (under `Libraries (-l)`) `glfw3`.
I have also added the path of the folder that contains `libglfw3.a` in `Library search path (-L)`.

However, the linker still returns an error when I try to compile.

My code is very basic and shown below.

```
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

int main() {
    glfwInit();
    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

The console output is:

```
make all 
Building target: TestProject
Invoking: MacOS X C++ Linker
g++  -o "TestProject"  ./src/Main.o  /Users/pixel/Documents/Library/libglfw3.a 
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_CFArrayAppendValue", referenced from:
      __glfwInitJoysticks in libglfw3.a(iokit_joystick.m.o)
      _addJoystickElement in libglfw3.a(iokit_joystick.m.o)
  "_CFArrayApplyFunction", referenced from:
      _matchCallback in libglfw3.a(iokit_joystick.m.o)
  "_CFArrayCreateMutable", referenced from:
      __glfwInitJoysticks in libglfw3.a(iokit_joystick.m.o)
      _matchCallback in libglfw3.a(iokit_joystick.m.o)
  "_CFArrayGetCount", referenced from:
      __glfwSetVideoMode in libglfw3.a(cocoa_monitor.m.o)
      __glfwPlatformGetVideoModes in libglfw3.a(cocoa_monitor.m.o)
      _matchCallback in libglfw3.a(iokit_joystick.m.o)
      _removeJoystick in libglfw3.a(iokit_joystick.m.o)
      _pollJoystickEvents in libglfw3.a(iokit_joystick.m.o)
      __glfwPlatformGetJoystickAxes in libglfw3.a(iokit_joystick.m.o)
      __glfwPlatformGetJoystickButtons in libglfw3.a(iokit_joystick.m.o)
      ...
  "_CFArrayGetValueAtIndex", referenced from:
      __glfwSetVideoMode in libglfw3.a(cocoa_monitor.m.o)
      __glfwPlatformGetVideoModes in libglfw3.a(cocoa_monitor.m.o)
      _removeJoystick in libglfw3.a(iokit_joystick.m.o)
      _pollJoystickEvents in libglfw3.a(iokit_joystick.m.o)
  "_CFArrayRemoveAllValues", referenced from:
      _removeJoystick in libglfw3.a(iokit_joystick.m.o)
  "_CFBundleCopyResourcesDirectoryURL", referenced from:
      _changeToResourcesDirectory in libglfw3.a(cocoa_init.m.o)
  "_CFBundleGetBundleWithIdentifier", referenced from:
      __glfwInitContextAPI in libglfw3.a(nsgl_context.m.o)
  "_CFBundleGetFunctionPointerForName", referenced from:
      __glfwPlatformGetProcAddress in libglfw3.a(nsgl_context.m.o)
  "_CFBundleGetMainBundle", referenced from:
      _changeToResourcesDirectory in libglfw3.a(cocoa_init.m.o)
  "_CFDictionaryCreateMutable", referenced from:
      _createMatchingDictionary in libglfw3.a(iokit_joystick.m.o)
  "_CFDictionaryGetValue", referenced from:
      _getDisplayName in libglfw3.a(cocoa_monitor.m.o)
  "_CFDictionaryGetValueIfPresent", referenced from:
      _getDisplayName in libglfw3.a(cocoa_monitor.m.o)
  "_CFDictionarySetValue", referenced from:
      _createMatchingDictionary in libglfw3.a(iokit_joystick.m.o)
  "_CFGetTypeID", referenced from:
      _getElementsCFArrayHandler in libglfw3.a(iokit_joystick.m.o)
  "_CFNumberCreate", referenced from:
      _createMatchingDictionary in libglfw3.a(iokit_joystick.m.o)
  "_CFRelease", referenced from:
      __glfwSetVideoMode in libglfw3.a(cocoa_monitor.m.o)
      _modeIsGood in libglfw3.a(cocoa_monitor.m.o)
      _vidmodeFromCGDisplayMode in libglfw3.a(cocoa_monitor.m.o)
      _getDisplayName in libglfw3.a(cocoa_monitor.m.o)
      __glfwPlatformGetVideoModes in libglfw3.a(cocoa_monitor.m.o)
      _changeToResourcesDirectory in libglfw3.a(cocoa_init.m.o)
      __glfwPlatformTerminate in libglfw3.a(cocoa_init.m.o)
      ...
  "_CFRunLoopGetMain", referenced from:
      __glfwInitJoysticks in libglfw3.a(iokit_joystick.m.o)
  "_CFRunLoopRunInMode", referenced from:
      __glfwInitJoysticks in libglfw3.a(iokit_joystick.m.o)
  "_CFStringCompare", referenced from:
      _modeIsGood in libglfw3.a(cocoa_monitor.m.o)
      _vidmodeFromCGDisplayMode in libglfw3.a(cocoa_monitor.m.o)
      _changeToResourcesDirectory in libglfw3.a(cocoa_init.m.o)
  "_CFStringCreateWithCString", referenced from:
      __glfwPlatformGetProcAddress in libglfw3.a(nsgl_context.m.o)
  "_CFStringGetCString", referenced from:
      _getDisplayName in libglfw3.a(cocoa_monitor.m.o)
      _matchCallback in libglfw3.a(iokit_joystick.m.o)
  "_CFStringGetLength", referenced from:
      _getDisplayName in libglfw3.a(cocoa_monitor.m.o)
  "_CFStringGetMaximumSizeForEncoding", referenced from:
      _getDisplayName in libglfw3.a(cocoa_monitor.m.o)
  "_CFURLCopyLastPathComponent", referenced from:
      _changeToResourcesDirectory in libglfw3.a(cocoa_init.m.o)
  "_CFURLGetFileSystemRepresentation", referenced from:
      _changeToResourcesDirectory in libglfw3.a(cocoa_init.m.o)
  "_CGAcquireDisplayFadeReservation", referenced from:
      _beginFadeReservation in libglfw3.a(cocoa_monitor.m.o)
  "_CGAssociateMouseAndMouseCursorPosition", referenced from:
      __glfwPlatformApplyCursorMode in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
  "_CGDisplayBounds", referenced from:
      _transformY in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
      __glfwPlatformGetMonitorPos in libglfw3.a(cocoa_monitor.m.o)
  "_CGDisplayCopyAllDisplayModes", referenced from:
      __glfwSetVideoMode in libglfw3.a(cocoa_monitor.m.o)
      __glfwPlatformGetVideoModes in libglfw3.a(cocoa_monitor.m.o)
  "_CGDisplayCopyDisplayMode", referenced from:
      __glfwSetVideoMode in libglfw3.a(cocoa_monitor.m.o)
      __glfwPlatformGetVideoMode in libglfw3.a(cocoa_monitor.m.o)
  "_CGDisplayFade", referenced from:
      _beginFadeReservation in libglfw3.a(cocoa_monitor.m.o)
      _endFadeReservation in libglfw3.a(cocoa_monitor.m.o)
  "_CGDisplayGammaTableCapacity", referenced from:
      __glfwPlatformGetGammaRamp in libglfw3.a(cocoa_monitor.m.o)
  "_CGDisplayIOServicePort", referenced from:
      _getDisplayName in libglfw3.a(cocoa_monitor.m.o)
  "_CGDisplayIsAsleep", referenced from:
      __glfwPlatformGetMonitors in libglfw3.a(cocoa_monitor.m.o)
  "_CGDisplayModeCopyPixelEncoding", referenced from:
      _modeIsGood in libglfw3.a(cocoa_monitor.m.o)
      _vidmodeFromCGDisplayMode in libglfw3.a(cocoa_monitor.m.o)
  "_CGDisplayModeGetHeight", referenced from:
      _vidmodeFromCGDisplayMode in libglfw3.a(cocoa_monitor.m.o)
  "_CGDisplayModeGetIOFlags", referenced from:
      _modeIsGood in libglfw3.a(cocoa_monitor.m.o)
  "_CGDisplayModeGetRefreshRate", referenced from:
      _vidmodeFromCGDisplayMode in libglfw3.a(cocoa_monitor.m.o)
  "_CGDisplayModeGetWidth", referenced from:
      _vidmodeFromCGDisplayMode in libglfw3.a(cocoa_monitor.m.o)
  "_CGDisplayModeRelease", referenced from:
      __glfwPlatformGetVideoMode in libglfw3.a(cocoa_monitor.m.o)
      __glfwRestoreVideoMode in libglfw3.a(cocoa_monitor.m.o)
  "_CGDisplayMoveCursorToPoint", referenced from:
      __glfwPlatformSetCursorPos in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
  "_CGDisplayScreenSize", referenced from:
      __glfwPlatformGetMonitors in libglfw3.a(cocoa_monitor.m.o)
  "_CGDisplaySetDisplayMode", referenced from:
      __glfwSetVideoMode in libglfw3.a(cocoa_monitor.m.o)
      __glfwRestoreVideoMode in libglfw3.a(cocoa_monitor.m.o)
  "_CGDisplayUnitNumber", referenced from:
      __glfwPlatformGetMonitors in libglfw3.a(cocoa_monitor.m.o)
  "_CGEventSourceCreate", referenced from:
      __glfwPlatformInit in libglfw3.a(cocoa_init.m.o)
  "_CGEventSourceSetLocalEventsSuppressionInterval", referenced from:
      __glfwPlatformInit in libglfw3.a(cocoa_init.m.o)
  "_CGGetDisplayTransferByTable", referenced from:
      __glfwPlatformGetGammaRamp in libglfw3.a(cocoa_monitor.m.o)
  "_CGGetOnlineDisplayList", referenced from:
      __glfwPlatformGetMonitors in libglfw3.a(cocoa_monitor.m.o)
  "_CGMainDisplayID", referenced from:
      _transformY in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
  "_CGReleaseDisplayFadeReservation", referenced from:
      _endFadeReservation in libglfw3.a(cocoa_monitor.m.o)
  "_CGSetDisplayTransferByTable", referenced from:
      __glfwPlatformSetGammaRamp in libglfw3.a(cocoa_monitor.m.o)
  "_CGWarpMouseCursorPosition", referenced from:
      __glfwPlatformSetCursorPos in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
  "_CGWindowLevelForKey", referenced from:
      _createWindow in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
  "_CVDisplayLinkCreateWithCGDisplay", referenced from:
      __glfwSetVideoMode in libglfw3.a(cocoa_monitor.m.o)
      __glfwPlatformGetVideoMode in libglfw3.a(cocoa_monitor.m.o)
      __glfwPlatformGetVideoModes in libglfw3.a(cocoa_monitor.m.o)
  "_CVDisplayLinkGetNominalOutputVideoRefreshPeriod", referenced from:
      _vidmodeFromCGDisplayMode in libglfw3.a(cocoa_monitor.m.o)
  "_CVDisplayLinkRelease", referenced from:
      __glfwSetVideoMode in libglfw3.a(cocoa_monitor.m.o)
      __glfwPlatformGetVideoMode in libglfw3.a(cocoa_monitor.m.o)
      __glfwPlatformGetVideoModes in libglfw3.a(cocoa_monitor.m.o)
  "_IODisplayCreateInfoDictionary", referenced from:
      _getDisplayName in libglfw3.a(cocoa_monitor.m.o)
  "_IOHIDDeviceCopyMatchingElements", referenced from:
      _matchCallback in libglfw3.a(iokit_joystick.m.o)
  "_IOHIDDeviceGetProperty", referenced from:
      _matchCallback in libglfw3.a(iokit_joystick.m.o)
  "_IOHIDDeviceGetValue", referenced from:
      _getElementValue in libglfw3.a(iokit_joystick.m.o)
  "_IOHIDElementGetLogicalMax", referenced from:
      _addJoystickElement in libglfw3.a(iokit_joystick.m.o)
  "_IOHIDElementGetLogicalMin", referenced from:
      _addJoystickElement in libglfw3.a(iokit_joystick.m.o)
  "_IOHIDElementGetType", referenced from:
      _addJoystickElement in libglfw3.a(iokit_joystick.m.o)
  "_IOHIDElementGetTypeID", referenced from:
      _getElementsCFArrayHandler in libglfw3.a(iokit_joystick.m.o)
  "_IOHIDElementGetUsage", referenced from:
      _addJoystickElement in libglfw3.a(iokit_joystick.m.o)
  "_IOHIDElementGetUsagePage", referenced from:
      _addJoystickElement in libglfw3.a(iokit_joystick.m.o)
  "_IOHIDManagerCreate", referenced from:
      __glfwInitJoysticks in libglfw3.a(iokit_joystick.m.o)
  "_IOHIDManagerOpen", referenced from:
      __glfwInitJoysticks in libglfw3.a(iokit_joystick.m.o)
  "_IOHIDManagerRegisterDeviceMatchingCallback", referenced from:
      __glfwInitJoysticks in libglfw3.a(iokit_joystick.m.o)
  "_IOHIDManagerRegisterDeviceRemovalCallback", referenced from:
      __glfwInitJoysticks in libglfw3.a(iokit_joystick.m.o)
  "_IOHIDManagerScheduleWithRunLoop", referenced from:
      __glfwInitJoysticks in libglfw3.a(iokit_joystick.m.o)
  "_IOHIDManagerSetDeviceMatchingMultiple", referenced from:
      __glfwInitJoysticks in libglfw3.a(iokit_joystick.m.o)
  "_IOHIDValueGetIntegerValue", referenced from:
      _getElementValue in libglfw3.a(iokit_joystick.m.o)
  "_NSApp", referenced from:
      -[GLFWApplicationDelegate applicationDidFinishLaunching:] in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
      __glfwPlatformPostEmptyEvent in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
      _initializeAppKit in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
      __glfwPlatformShowWindow in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
      __glfwPlatformPollEvents in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
      __glfwPlatformWaitEvents in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
      _createMenuBar in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
      ...
  "_NSAppKitVersionNumber", referenced from:
      _convertRectToBacking in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
      -[GLFWContentView scrollWheel:] in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
      _createWindow in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
      _createMenuBar in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
  "_NSCalibratedRGBColorSpace", referenced from:
      __glfwPlatformCreateCursor in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
  "_NSDefaultRunLoopMode", referenced from:
      __glfwPlatformPollEvents in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
      __glfwPlatformWaitEvents in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
  "_NSFilenamesPboardType", referenced from:
      -[GLFWContentView initWithGlfwWindow:] in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
      -[GLFWContentView performDragOperation:] in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
  "_NSSelectorFromString", referenced from:
      _createMenuBar in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
  "_NSStringPboardType", referenced from:
      __glfwPlatformSetClipboardString in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
      __glfwPlatformGetClipboardString in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
  "_NSZeroPoint", referenced from:
      +[GLFWContentView initialize] in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSApplication", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_GLFWApplication in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSArray", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSAutoreleasePool", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
      objc-class-ref in libglfw3.a(cocoa_init.m.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSBitmapImageRep", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSBundle", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSCursor", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSDate", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSEvent", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSImage", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSMenu", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSMenuItem", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSObject", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_GLFWWindowDelegate in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_GLFWApplicationDelegate in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSOpenGLContext", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libglfw3.a(nsgl_context.m.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSOpenGLPixelFormat", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libglfw3.a(nsgl_context.m.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSPasteboard", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSString", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSTrackingArea", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSView", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_GLFWContentView in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSWindow", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_GLFWWindow in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_NSApplication", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GLFWApplication in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_NSObject", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GLFWWindowDelegate in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GLFWApplicationDelegate in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GLFWContentView in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GLFWWindow in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GLFWApplication in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_NSView", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GLFWContentView in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_NSWindow", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GLFWWindow in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
  "___CFConstantStringClassReference", referenced from:
      CFString in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
      CFString in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
      CFString in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
      CFString in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
      CFString in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
      CFString in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
      CFString in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
      ...
  "__objc_empty_cache", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_GLFWWindowDelegate in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GLFWWindowDelegate in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GLFWApplicationDelegate in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_GLFWApplicationDelegate in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_GLFWContentView in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GLFWContentView in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GLFWWindow in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
      ...
  "_kCFAllocatorDefault", referenced from:
      __glfwPlatformGetProcAddress in libglfw3.a(nsgl_context.m.o)
      __glfwInitJoysticks in libglfw3.a(iokit_joystick.m.o)
      _createMatchingDictionary in libglfw3.a(iokit_joystick.m.o)
  "_kCFRunLoopDefaultMode", referenced from:
      __glfwInitJoysticks in libglfw3.a(iokit_joystick.m.o)
  "_kCFTypeArrayCallBacks", referenced from:
      __glfwInitJoysticks in libglfw3.a(iokit_joystick.m.o)
  "_kCFTypeDictionaryKeyCallBacks", referenced from:
      _createMatchingDictionary in libglfw3.a(iokit_joystick.m.o)
  "_kCFTypeDictionaryValueCallBacks", referenced from:
      _createMatchingDictionary in libglfw3.a(iokit_joystick.m.o)
  "_objc_msgSend", referenced from:
      -[GLFWWindowDelegate windowDidResize:] in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
      -[GLFWWindowDelegate windowDidMove:] in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
      _enterFullscreenMode in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
      __glfwPlatformIconifyWindow in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
      -[GLFWApplicationDelegate applicationDidFinishLaunching:] in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
      __glfwPlatformPostEmptyEvent in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
      +[GLFWContentView initialize] in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
      ...
  "_objc_msgSendSuper2", referenced from:
      -[GLFWWindowDelegate initWithGlfwWindow:] in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
      -[GLFWContentView initWithGlfwWindow:] in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
      -[GLFWContentView dealloc] in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
      -[GLFWContentView updateTrackingAreas] in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
      -[GLFWApplication sendEvent:] in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
  "_objc_msgSend_stret", referenced from:
      -[GLFWWindowDelegate windowDidResize:] in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
      _convertRectToBacking in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
      __glfwPlatformGetWindowPos in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
      -[GLFWContentView mouseMoved:] in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
      -[GLFWContentView viewDidChangeBackingProperties] in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
      -[GLFWContentView updateTrackingAreas] in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
      -[GLFWContentView performDragOperation:] in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
      ...
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [TestProject] Error 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [GLFW: Building Applications](http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/build.html):

> If you are using the static library version of GLFW, add it and the Cocoa, OpenGL, IOKit and CoreVideo frameworks to the project as dependencies. They can all be found in /System/Library/Frameworks.

Add the frameworks above like so:

`g++ -o "TestProject"  ./src/Main.o  /Users/pixel/Documents/Library/libglfw3.a -framework Cocoa -framework OpenGL -framework IOKit -framework CoreVideo`

As for adding compiler flags in Eclipse Mars, I personally don't use Eclipse but here's what I found (from [here](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.pde.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Fpde_compiler_options.htm)):

> Custom compiler arguments can now be specified per bundle using the **compilerArg property** in the bundle's **build.properties** file ...